# How to deploy statefulset in Kubernetes Federation?

Tags: kubernetes, federation, statefulset

It seems like the federation api currently doesn't support statefulset deployment, but I would like to know is that possible to deploy statefulsets in Kubernetes Federation in the situation described below.

For example, for three pods: pod-0, pod-1, pod-2 are running on cluster A, and pod-3, pod-4, pod5 are running on cluster B?